# Move js code from html page to js file and call that code in my html page

Tags: javascript, zend-framework

Hi guys i am trying to move my js code from my phtml page to js page and i would like to call to that page in to my phtml page. And i am working in zend.

Can anyone help me how can i do that.

here is my phtml code:

```
   <div class="reminderForm">
    <form id="reminderForm_<?php echo $this->ticketId;?>">
        <h4><?php echo $this->translate('set_reminder'); ?></h4>
        <span class="formz-required">*</span>
        <?php echo $this->form->remark;?>
        <?php if ($this->isAllowed('ticket.index.reminder-type')) : ?>
            <span class="remark-element-span formz-required">*</span>
            <?php echo $this->form->reminderType;
        endif; ?>
        <span class="remark-element-span formz-required">*</span>
        <?php
            echo $this->form->reopenTicket;
            echo $this->form->ticketId; 
        ?>
        <div class="button-block">
            <span><?php echo $this->form->cancel; ?></span>
            <span><?php echo $this->form->save; ?></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<?php 
echo $this->inlineScript()->appendScript(<<<EOS
    $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/themes/bas/icons/fatcow/16x16/calendar.png",
        dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
        buttonImageOnly: true, 
        controlType: 'select',
        showWeek: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        oneLine : true
    });
    var today = new Date();
    var tomorrow = new Date(); 
    tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
    tomorrow.setHours(8);
    tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
    $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(tomorrow));
EOS
);
?>
```

And here is my js file :

```
    var REMINDER = {};

REMINDER.Followupreminder = {

};
```

inside that

```
 REMINDER.Followupreminder = {

};
```

function i would like to call that js code.

Can anyone help me how can i do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you provided additional info (initial request was out of context) here's something similar to your sample:

```
var REMINDER = {};

REMINDER.Followupreminder = {

    init: function(){
        // put your any initialization here
        this.bindUI();
    },

    bindUI: function(){
        // if bindUI isn't being used from outside - you may call this.initDatePicker() directly from init()
        this.initDatePicker();
    },

    initDatePicker: function () {
        console.log('Congratulations! Your code has been moved and executed!');
        $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "/themes/bas/icons/fatcow/16x16/calendar.png",
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            controlType: 'select',
            showWeek: true,
            firstDay: 1,
            oneLine: true
        });
        var today = new Date();
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
        tomorrow.setHours(8);
        tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
        $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker("setDate", new Date(tomorrow));
    }
};

$(function(){
    REMINDER.Followupreminder.init();
});
```

Comment: i am getting  formal parameter name expected from this line $(".reopenTicket").datetimepicker({

Comment: no actually i would like to keep my js code inside my  REMINDER.Followupreminder = {

};

Comment: but the synax you used `{}` is not a function, it's an object, you can't place executable code there. Unless you add some method. Not enough info yet to help you. Provide a sample of how you want to call your function

Comment: https://codeshare.io/5znKLb check that we used to follow this kind of structure in my office to the js code

Comment: probably you meant to use your function as a method, check my updated answer

Comment: yes ..as i saw you have used function myFunction(){ } but as per my rules we wont use any function name like this we will directly call inside that object it will work as we have built in functions which can work in the way

Comment: do you want your code be wrapped like what you shown? That `TICKET` module has `TICKET.preview.init()` call at the bottom which does all the initialization btw

Comment: yes i want my code to be like what i have shown in my example file

Comment: you should have provide this info in your initial question post. Let me update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183759/discussion-between-roman86-and-suresh).